# Safe way to view json currently being written by Python code

Tags: python

I have a script I'm running a bunch of times that generates and logs data in json files. These take days to run and I need to run several dozen test cases. I log progress in json files for post-processing. I'd like to check in occasionally to see how long it has left. This is all single thread, but I've dealt with multiprocessing enough to be scared of opening the file while it's being written for fear that viewing it will place a temporary lock on the file.

1. Is it safe to view the json in a linux terminal using `nano log_file.json` while my Python scripts are running and could attempt to write to the log at any time?
2. If it is not safe, are there any alternatives?

I'm worried if Python tries to record an entry that it could be lost or throw an error while I'm viewing progress. Viewing only, no saving obviously. I'd love to check in on progress to switch between test cases faster, but I really don't want to raise an error that loses days of progress if it's unable to write to the json.

Sorry if this is a duplicate, I tried searching but I'm not sure what to even search for this question.

Comment: Why not, either instead of or in tandem, use python logging? You can have rotating filehandlers and all sorts of options. If you really want to go the read from same file route you should use some try: except: statements and withs and it's kind of a big mess :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **tail** command on terminal to view the logs. Following is the full command:-

```
tail -F <path_to_file>
```

It will show some of the last lines of the file and continue to show if data is being written in the file.